# Unable to allocate the free space to main volume

Tags: disk-utility, partition, macos, diskutil

I've been trying to allocate the left unallocated free space after uninstalling the ubuntu. As there are no options available in disk utility to do that now.

[image: Disk Utility]

The unshaded part is unallocated.
I tried to workaround using terminal commands but I am getting an error that I am not able to understand.
I ran the command

```
diskutil coreStorage resizeStack FCF7976D-78ED-4CE9-8029-C6557CB601C5 429.9G JHFS+ Mac 480G
```

and got

```
The Core Storage Logical Volume UUID is FCF7976D-78ED-4CE9-8029-C6557CB601C5
Started CoreStorage operation
Checking prerequisites for resizing Logical-Physical volume stack
Error: -69722: You can't perform this resize unless it has a booter (target  partition is probably too small)
```

What is this error and how to get around it to get back my free space of hard drive?

---

Link for the commands. http://blog.fosketts.net/2011/08/05/undocumented-corestorage-commands/
You can also refer to apple's man page on diskutil

Edit1 :

```
~ diskutil list
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        *500.1 GB   disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            429.9 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
   4:        Bios Boot Partition                         1.0 MB     disk0s4
   5:                 Linux Swap                         4.1 GB     disk0s5
   6:           Linux Filesystem                         65.3 GB    disk0s6

/dev/disk1 (internal, virtual):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                            Macintosh HD           +429.5 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 FCF7976D-78ED-4CE9-8029-C6557CB601C5
                                 Unencrypted

~ sudo gpt show disk0
gpt show: disk0: Suspicious MBR at sector 0
      start       size  index  contents
          0          1         MBR
          1          1         Pri GPT header
          2         32         Pri GPT table
         34          6
         40     409600      1  GPT part - C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B
     409640  839592368      2  GPT part - 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  840002008    1269536      3  GPT part - 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC
  841271544       1800
  841273344       2048      4  GPT part - 21686148-6449-6E6F-744E-656564454649
  841275392    7999488      5  GPT part - 0657FD6D-A4AB-43C4-84E5-0933C84B4F4F
  849274880  127496192      6  GPT part - 0FC63DAF-8483-4772-8E79-3D69D8477DE4
  976771072       2063
  976773135         32         Sec GPT table
  976773167          1         Sec GPT header
```

Comment: Please add the output of `diskutil list` and `sudo gpt -r diskX` with diskX: the disk identifier of the HDD (prob. disk0). Please add is as formatted text  and **not** as screenshot.

Comment: @klanomath here are the outputs.

Answer (score 1):

The command `diskutil cs resizeStack ...` requires some unallocated disk space at the end of a Logical Volume Group and the Recovery HD (index 2 & 3) to be able to expand it. You only have 1800 blocks à 512 Bytes (~2 MB) of it.

After installing and uninstalling Ubuntu you still have an abandoned BIOS Boot partition (probably GRUB) (index 4), a swap partition (index 5) and a main Linux partition (index 6) at the tail of your disk.

Before resizing the CS stack (which often fails with such an expelled Linux dual-boot environment), you have to delete the three Linux partitions (and change the MBR to the default pMBR).

- Backup your internal drive
- Detach any external drive
- Boot to Internet Recovery Mode
- Open Terminal in the menubar Utilities -> Terminal
- Get an overview (especially the *gpt* command is important!). Below I assume the internal disk has the disk identifier disk0 and the Logical Volume residing in disk0s2 has the disk identifier disk2. Please use the disk identifiers you found in **your** environment:

  ```
  diskutil list
  gpt -r show disk0
  ```
- Unmount first the Logical VOlume and then the internal disk:

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk2
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```
- Delete the MBR:

  ```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=/dev/disk0 bs=512 count=1
  ```
- Destroy the GUID partition table and create a new one (this also creates a fresh pMBR):

  ```
  gpt destroy disk0
  gpt create -f disk0
  ```
- Rebuild all previous GUID partitions:

  ```
  gpt add -i 1 -b 40 -s 409600 -t C12A7328-F81F-11D2-BA4B-00A0C93EC93B disk0
  gpt add -i 3 -b 840002008 -s 1269536 -t 426F6F74-0000-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  gpt add -i 2 -b 409640 -s 839592368 -t 53746F72-6167-11AA-AA11-00306543ECAC disk0
  ```

  If you get a resource busy error after one of the steps, just unmount disk0 again with

  ```
  diskutil umountDisk /dev/disk0
  ```

Check the disk with `diskutil verifyDisk disk0` afterwards.

Enter `diskutil cs list` and check if all four CoreStorage containers appear: a Logical Volume Group, a Physical Volume and Logical Volume Family and a Logical Volume.

With the UUID of the Logical Volume mount the LV:

Example:

```
    +-> Logical Volume FCF7976D-78ED-4CE9-8029-C6557CB601C5
        ---------------------------------------------------
        Disk:                  disk17
        Status:                Online
```

Then use:

```
diskutil mount FCF7976D-78ED-4CE9-8029-C6557CB601C5
```

Then after getting the disk identifier of the mounted LV with `diskutil list` verify the volume:

```
diskutil verifyVolume disk17 #probably it's disk17, disk16 or disk18
```

Then try to resize the stack with:

```
diskutil cs resizeStack FCF7976D-78ED-4CE9-8029-C6557CB601C5 499g
```

If you get an error (partition is too small) use a slightly smaller value (e.g. 498500m)

---

The above resizeStack command may fail, due to a CS LVG "corruption". This is no corruption of your data but probably a corruption/misconfiguration of some CS meta data. Then you have to wipe your disk and restore your current (Time Machine) backup.

Comment: thanks for the help, but I followed another method which worked fine.
I used live ubuntu bootable usb and used gparted tool to delete the unallocated drive and then again creating a new drive with ntfs format. Then I used tuxera ntfs to access the partition on my mac. Now I have both the partitions accessible.